# Batch File : could not open specific file with WordPad and save it

Tags: batch-file

Initially I captured a file using batch file and it is open with Notepad. How do I code the batch file so that it will save with WordPad.

Batch File :

```
Remarks:This document is for Linksys for version v4.30.5, the auto sensing part.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless Guard\wget" "http://192.168.1.254/xslt@PAGE=C_2_0"
copy "xslt@PAGE=C_2_0" "xslt@PAGE=C_2_0.txt"
del "xslt@PAGE=C_2_0"
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? A batch file is plain text, so it will save in any editor capable of saving in that format (Notepad, WordPad, Notepad++, etc.)

Comment: I can't imagine anything you can do about the batch file itself to either enable or disable its opening with WordPad. Your question is more likely to have to do with *how* you are trying to open batch files in WordPad. And questions of that kind probably belong on [su].

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do anything to get it to save with WordPad as such. As previously commented batch files output to plain text so you can open it with WordPad if you wish.

You could do this in batch with:

`write txtfile.txt`

Or to permanently associate WordPad set it as your default txt program in Control Panel.

Hope this helps.